# How to show the status of restaurant open/closed in react using state object

Tags: reactjs

Restaurants Availability Route
Users should be able to see the restaurant immediate availability time if the restaurant is closed currently.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has no example code and doesn't effectively explain the problem. It seems like you need to use react state.